# How to remove this space in JetBrains IDE's?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

My PHPStorm is unconfigured. Few days ago, editor has space between number line and gutter icons like this image:

[image: Editor it's crazy]

How to remove this space?
Thanks!

Comment: Presentation/Distraction free/Full screen mode active? Try exiting it.

Comment: I disabled Distraction mode and works!! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like Distraction Free mode active .. or unwanted post effect after exiting Presentation mode (happens sometimes).

In first case -- just exit "Distraction Free mode" (from `View` menu); in 2nd case -- restarting IDE should fix it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/phpstorm-viewing-modes.html